# Rails dynamic form remote true controller not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic

I am trying to establish a dynamic form on a contact's page. I would like on this page to be a  link that says "add an email address" and then when I click on it, a form appears to enter email address.

So I used a link_to with remote true :

```
  = link_to "Add an email", add_email_path, id:'link-remote-link', remote: true
```

In my controller i specified :

```
  def add_email
    render layout: false
  end
```

But when I receive my response with listening on ajax:sucess, layout is still their in the variable. But I just want the form add_email.html.haml

In order to try to know if the code in my controller was executed, I tryed to put a creation of an object in it. Fact is that it was never created.

Never the less, rails console writes "Processing by ContactsController#add_email as JS
"

So...why is it not executed ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Layout**

We set the layout in the `application_controller` to manage the ajax responses:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout Proc.new { |controller| !controller.request.xhr? }
end
```

You may wish to try this - to see if it's the call in your controller which is rendering the layout.

Personally, I think your `layout: false` call is being overridden with some other element / part of your controller. I'd recommend checking to make sure this is the case

--

**Controller**

As you've stated, the case *may* be that your controller isn't being called, or processed correctly.

This could be caused by a number of issues, most notably from having incorrect routes, or some other dependency preventing the method from firing properly.

To clarify, I would make sure I have the following set up:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :contacts do
   get :add_email, on: :collection
end

#app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
   def add_email
      ...
   end
end
```

Comment: If you want to go into chat about this, please just reply to this comment

Comment: This actually seems to be a proper way to organize code. 

Anyways, I don't know if it was what you wanted to tell me, but I've put my "add_email" action at the begining of the controller instead of at the end. And it magically works...

I don't really understand why.

Comment: Do you have a private declaration in there at all?

Comment: No private declaration